React 18 + SyncFusion: DateTimePicker inside ColumnDirective
In React 18 with TypeScript, SyncFusion EJ2, I have the following Grid:
    <GridComponent
      height={'100%'}
      width={width ? width : 'auto'}
      dataSource={eventDateList}
      ref={gridInstance}
      toolbar={toolbarOptions}
      allowSorting={true}
      allowPaging={true}
      editSettings={editSettings}
      pageSettings={{ pageCount: 10, pageSize: 50 }}
      actionBegin={actionBegin.bind(this)}
    >
      <ColumnsDirective>
        <ColumnDirective visible={false} field="id" headerText="ID" width="15" textAlign="Left" validationRules={idRules} isPrimaryKey={true} />
        <ColumnDirective format="HH:mm" field="endTime" headerText="Zeit" editType="datetimepickeredit"></ColumnDirective>
      </ColumnsDirective>
      <Inject services={[Page, Toolbar, Edit, Sort]} />
    </GridComponent>

Current Behaviour:
When I click the column "endTime", I can select a date and the time.
Desired Behaviour:
When I click on the column "endTime", I can only select a time, not a date.
